# Understandig proof of a theorem on finite fields.

Tags: finite-fields

The theorem statement is: a finite field of characteristic $p$ has $p^n$ elements. I found this very simple proof in the book "Ling, San; Xing, Chaoping; Coding Theory - A First Course". But I don't understand the highlighted step. Doesn't that require $(b_2-a_2)|(a_1-b_1)$?

[image]

Comment: If one thinks of $b_2-a_2$ not as an integer, but as an element of the field $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ then that's OK.

Comment: It's a field, every element has an inverse. Integers don't have inverses in the ring of integers, but they do in the ring of integers mod $p$. For instance, $2^{-1}\equiv 3$ in ${\bf Z}_5$ even though of course $\frac{1}{2}$ is not an integer.

Comment: Yes you are right. I missed that. I was assuming those were integers.

Comment: @runway44 of course you meant every *nonzero* element has an inverse.

Comment: This is unnecessarily technical and blurs the view on what is really going on. Maybe you should switch to a better coding theory book (there are very nice choices). The usual proof is to see that the integer multiples of $1$ form a subfield $P$ of order $p$ (the *prime field* of $P$), and that $F$ is a vector space over $P$. Both are direct consequences of the field axioms. By linear algebra (two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension), $F$ is isomorphic to $P^n$ for some positive integer $n$. Hence $\#F = \#(P^n) = p^n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The field is a vector space of finite dimension over its prime sub-field.